# theme magento 2 not working

Tags: magento2, theme, css, requirejs

I installed magento 2 on my computer and I copied the   code of the theme in the `app\design` and `pub\` that works on the server but it does not work properly on my computer.
Help

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried clearing cache?

Comment: please check with cs, js urls in inspect elements if you get 404 than execute upgrade,deploy etc commands apply.

Comment: yes I clear the cache and all good for css and js I have no errors at the console

Answer (score 0):

1. Upgrade the set up using the commands:

   php bin/magento setup:upgrade;
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
2. Log in to the Admin Panel:
   Go to the Content>Design>Configuration and choose Edit the store theme and select the desired theme from the dropdown menu and click the Save Configuration button.